# Script Content Type Actix Web

Tags: rust, content-type, actix-web

The content type script does not exist in the actix web framework.
But is there any other way to tell the browser that the sent file is a script?
this would be the http response i used

```rust
        Response::JS => {
        HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type(ContentType::/*what needs to be here???*/)
        .insert_header(("X-Hdr", "sample"))
        .body(x)
        }
```

as cdhowie suggest

```
.content_type(mime::APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT)
```

works thx

Comment: Probably `ContentType(mime::APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT)` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContentType` is a tuple struct with a single `Mime` value.  You probably want `mime::APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT`, so you should be able to use `.content_type(ContentType(mime::APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT))`.  It also looks like you can supply a `Mime` value directly: `.content_type(mime::APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT)`.